# Weird frame around the image in MS Outlook 2013 (Windows 7)

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, outlook-2013, litmus

I'm using the image as a background in my HTML-email, to get the ability to allocate text and button over the top layer of the image and it is working fine for every email client beside the MS Outlook 2013 on Windows 7.

For some reason, once the user got the email and click on the button (or wherever image area) there is weird frame appears around the image and that frame looks like user can edit that image (rotate or resize), but he can't, it's just a frame.

I can't figure out how can I get rid of that frame. Another problem is the Litmus doesn't show any issue with the code so it's kina like impossible to fix without actual sending. Please help!

Using all header as one image isn't an option because the client requires the ability to change the text over himself.

Below the part of the code for the header only but here is the link on the code of the entire email https://pastebin.com/edYR2eVm and the Litmus project https://litmus.com/builder/da4ef27

[image: photo of the issue]

```
            <!-- HERO : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <!-- Bulletproof Background Images c/o https://backgrounds.cm -->
                <td background="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSYiUYrvVY_LbHtpJf-iiBrk_3BXOwqHyulAj0sDk3gJKOxAl6FkA" bgcolor="#222222" align="center" valign="top" style="text-align: center; background-position: center center !important; background-size: cover !important;">
                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:680px; height:380px; background-position: center center !important;">
                    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSYiUYrvVY_LbHtpJf-iiBrk_3BXOwqHyulAj0sDk3gJKOxAl6FkA" color="#222222" />
                    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                    <![endif]-->
                    <div>
                        <!--[if mso]>
                        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="500">
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="middle" width="500">
                        <![endif]-->
                        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width:500px; margin: auto;">

                            <tr>
                                <td height="20" style="font-size:20px; line-height:20px;">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" valign="middle">

                              <table>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td valign="top" style="text-align: center; padding: 60px 0 10px 20px;">

                                         <h1 style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-size: 30px; line-height: 36px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;">WELCOME %%FIRST NAME%%</h1>
                                     </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td valign="top" style="text-align: center; padding: 10px 20px 15px 20px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #fff;">
                                         <p style="margin: 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                         tempor incididunt ut labore.</p>
                                     </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td valign="top" align="center" style="text-align: center; padding: 15px 0px 60px 0px;">

                                         <!-- Button : BEGIN -->
                                         <center>
                                         <table role="presentation" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="center-on-narrow" style="text-align: center;">
                                             <tr>
                                                 <td style="border-radius: 50px; background: #26a4d3; text-align: center;" class="button-td">
                                                     <a href="http://www.google.com" style="background: #26a4d3; border: 15px solid #26a4d3; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 50px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a">
                                                         <span style="color:#ffffff;" class="button-link">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ACCESS ACCOUNT&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                                                     </a>
                                                 </td>
                                             </tr>
                                         </table>
                                         </center>
                                         <!-- Button : END -->

                                     </td>
                                 </tr> 
                              </table>

                              </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td height="20" style="font-size:20px; line-height:20px;">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                        <!--[if mso]>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]-->
                    </div>
                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                    </v:textbox>
                    </v:rect>
                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- HERO : END -->
```

Comment: That is the result of VML being used on the email. VML is vector markup language native to Microsoft Outlook. There is no way of removing that outline as far as i can tell. If you do find a way please let us know

Comment: @Syfer thank you for your response! 
Have you got that issue in your email job? If so, please let me know what you did as a solution?

Comment: It's not an issue. That is how the functionality works. If there is a workaround then it should be online.